# Problem with leg_detector and people_tracking_filter

Tags: ros, leg-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS users !

I'd like to simulate a human wandering around with MORSE simulator and see the robot detecting it in rviz. I managed to install people stack from David Lu but got a couple of problems when I run it.

First I run filter.launch in people_tracking_filter package. Although I don't have any odom_combined frame as fixed frame, I replaced it with odom instead. /people_tracker_filter_visualization seems to be updated 10 times/s but is empty as shown with rostopic :

```
header: 
  seq: 375
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: odom
points: []
channels: 
  - 
    name: rgb
    values: []
```

So I run leg_detector.launch is the corresponding package but I get the following error :

```
[ERROR] [1378816996.919008120]: Client [/people_tracker] wants topic /people_tracker_measurements to have datatype/md5sum [people_msgs/PositionMeasurement/54fa938b4ec28728e01575b79eb0ec7c], but our version has [people_msgs/PositionMeasurementArray/59c860d40aa739ec920eb3ad24ae019e]. Dropping connection.
[ WARN] [1378817011.705600206]: MessageFilter [target=/odom_combined ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.leg_detector.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

So second thing : the launch file refers to base_scan topic but mine is empty, every data is contained in my scan topic. However replacing base_scan by scan doesn't change anything. And also there is still some things related to odom_combined ...

Any guess ?

Thank you very much for your time.

I'm running groovy on ubuntu 12.04, MORSE 1.1 simulator with a differential robot and a 2D LIDAR.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78026/problem-with-leg_detector-and-people_tracking_filter/) by [Rouno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4024/rouno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

people_tracking_filter is a compile dependency for leg_detector, but you should be able to run leg_detector without launching filter.launch.

To be honest, I switched a bunch of stuff around with PositionMeasurements and PositionMeasurementArrays, and so I might have broken some components I don't use. Please try just running  leg_detector.launch without the other launch file.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rouno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4024/rouno/) on 2013-09-11**:
If I launch leg_detector alone it's OK but neither /people_tracker_measurements nor /leg_tracker_measurements are updated.
However, I did noticed that the shape of the scan around the human avatar was a portion of a square. I guess this would explain why your package doesn't work. What do you think?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-09-22**:
I'm not sure I understand. Do you think the squares should be detected as legs?

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-09-23**:
It seems that, in MORSE simulator, the human shape is contained in a box, and the laser rangefinder detects only this box and not the real shape of the legs. So, Rouno was asking if you think this can be the reason why it's not working well.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-09-23**:
David, in which topic will the result be ? In /leg_tracker_measurements or /people_tracker_measurements ?
I managed to have the markers in Rviz, but no people seem to be detected. Concerning the markers, what is the difference between blue, red and black markers ?
Thanks